# What are $δ$ and $ε$ in the list of Dirac's five 'fundamental constants', concerning his 'Large number hypothesis'?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, gravity, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

From Jean-Philippe Uzan's Varying Constants, Gravitation and Cosmology:

Dirac formed five dimensionless ratios among which1 δ ≡ H0ħ/mpc2 ∼ 2h × 10−42 and equation M1 and asked the question of which of these ratios is constant as the universe evolves. Usually, δ varies as the inverse of the cosmic time while ϵ varies also with time if the universe is not described by an Einstein-de Sitter solution (i.e., when a cosmological constant, curvature or radiation are included in the cosmological model).

[image]

Perhaps I am a dunce, but does lowercase epsilon stand for the vacuum permittivity?

And I know he talks about lowercase delta repeatedly, but does not define exactly what it is (I don't believe he does).

And $h$ is, I presume, Planck's constant?  Just like h-bar is the reduced Planck constant (a.k.a. Dirac's constant)?

Comment: Check the units. The given formulae for $\delta,\,\epsilon$ make them dimensionless, so $h$ is too, whence it doesn't mean Planck's constant.

Answer (score 0):

The lower case $\epsilon$, the way he defined it, is the dimensionless density parameter. The (first) Friedmann equation (neglecting the curvature term) is:

$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho$

Then denoting the Hubble parameter today as $H_0$ and the mean matter density today as $\rho_0$, we can see that $\epsilon=G\rho_0/H_0^2$ is a dimensionless parameter. Please check Appendix A.3 where the author described it in some detail.